# Xcode 8.2: UIPageViewControllerDatasource method broken

Tags: ios, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller

I am working on an application that uses a `UIPageViewController` to present two main view controllers. I am subclassing the `UIPageViewController` and conforming to the `UIPageViewControllerDatasource` protocol. The methods in this protocol allow me to set the view controllers I want to display. But the following methods are giving me trouble.

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {}
```

and

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {}
```

The issue is the compiler keeps trying to get the parameters in the method to change. It will suggest I made a mistake and either `viewControllerAfter` or `viewControllerBefore` should be changed. And I keep getting stuck in this loop with this error, "`method 'pageViewController(_:viewControllerBefore:)' has different argument names from protocol 'UIPageViewControllerDatasource'`."

**BEFORE**

[image]

[image]

*Then I make the change as suggested*, and it persists.

**AFTER**

[image]

[image]

I need some pointers on how to get around this.

Comment: Are you using `override` on these methods?

Comment: I also saw this once in Xcode 8.1, and the error went away after I implemented both methods.

Comment: @Samantha you were right. Both methods needed to be implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to implement both methods. This should get rid of your errors.